# Preview image in MS Excel using VBA code at mouse hover

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I used the following code to preview the images from my local drive location. It is working but when i hover over the cell where i entered the reset() function, it deletes all my images in the worksheet.
I only want to make disappear the image that is shown from the hyperlink function. Can anybody help me in this regard. code is given below

```
Dim DoOnce As Boolean
Public Function OnMouseOver(URL As String, TheCell As Range)
Reset
If Not DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = True
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 300
        End With
        .Left = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column).Left
        .Top = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End If
End Function



Public Function Reset()
If DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = False
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
End If
End Function
```

I want that only image shown through hyperlink location is deleted when i mouse hover on the cell with reset() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the picture with `TopLeftCell`

```vb
Dim DoOnce As Boolean
Public Function OnMouseOver(URL As String, TheCell As Range)
    Reset TheCell  ' **
    If Not DoOnce Then
        DoOnce = True
        With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)
            With .ShapeRange
                .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                .Width = 300
                .Height = 300
            End With
            .Left = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column).Left
            .Top = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column).Top
            .Placement = 1
            .PrintObject = True
        End With
    End If
End Function
Public Sub Reset(rCell)
    If DoOnce Then
        DoOnce = False
        For Each p In ActiveSheet.Pictures ' **
           If p.TopLeftCell.Address = rCell.Address Then p.Delete  ' **
        Next ' **
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi
Thanks. its working with Public Function declaration but not working with Public Sub declaration. Thanks for your valuable help as the method worked for me.

Comment: `OnMouseOver` has to be a function. `Reset` can be either sub or function. The code is tested w/ Excel 365.

Comment: If you prefer to to use `Function Reset()`, you just need define a module-scope variable `Dim rCell as Range`. Then add a line `Set rCell = TheCell` in `OnMouseOver` before call Reset.

Comment: This perfectly worked. thanks for your much needed help.